# How do i get the value of dynamic input fields from javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic-forms

I am trying to make a dynamic form using a javascript function, but i'm amateur on this, so i'm not sure how to collect the inputs values, considering is a dynamic function. This is the HTML part:

```
<div>
   Amount of people: <input type="text" id="member" name="member" value=""><br />
   <button id="btn" onclick="addinputFields()">Show</button>
</div>
<form action="{{ url_for('red_preferente') }}" method="post">
     <div id="mydiv"/><br />
     <input type="submit" value="Quote"/>
</form>
```

And this is the JS function "addinputFields", im calling above

```
function addinputFields(){
var number = document.getElementById("member").value;

  for (i=0;i<number;i++){
      var campo_1 = document.createElement("output");
      campo_1.type = "text";
      campo_1.value = " Nombre: ";
      mydiv.appendChild(campo_1);

      var nombre = document.createElement("input");
      nombre.type = "text";
      nombre.id = "name"
      mydiv.appendChild(nombre);

      var campo_2 = document.createElement("output");
      campo_2.type = "text";
      campo_2.value = " Edad: ";
      mydiv.appendChild(campo_2);

      var edad = document.createElement("input");
      edad.type = "text";
      edad.id = "age"
      mydiv.appendChild(edad);

      var campo_3 = document.createElement("output");
      campo_3.type = "text";
      campo_3.value = " Modalidad: ";
      mydiv.appendChild(campo_3);

      var modalidades = ["Titular","Asegurado","Dependiente"];
      var listado = document.createElement("select");
      listado.id = "mySelect";

      for (var x = 0; x < modalidades.length; x++) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = modalidades[x];
          option.text = modalidades[x];
          listado.appendChild(option);
      }
      mydiv.appendChild(listado);
  }}
```

I'm trying to use "document.getElementById('mydiv').value" to have the input value, but i receive none value

I need each one of the input value of vars: nombre, edad, listado. Any idea?

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible causes of your problem. Because inputs are strings you should cast your input using

```
var number = parseInt(document.getElementById("member").value);
```

The problem seems to lie around the `createElement()` statements. Your `<variable name>.value` isn't right. That only works for the value of an `<input>` or `<textarea>`. Simpler would have been to get rid of the `createElement()`s. The

```
var campo_1 = document.createElement("output");
campo_1.type = "text";
campo_1.value = " Nombre: ";
mydiv.appendChild(campo_1);
```

lines could have easily been re-written

```
mydiv.innerHTML += "Nombre: ";
```

Comment: **[`<output>`](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/elements/3-output.html)** exists

Comment: @zer00ne Strange that I've never seen that tag before... I've deleted that section.